# ffmpeg Добавить аудиопоток

Tags: c, ffmpeg, c++

Добавить аудио поток, из одного файла в другой.          
Добавил новую программу в выходной-файл.

```
av_new_stream( pFormatCtxOutFl, newIDProgram );
```

Скопировал туда все параметры из файла-источника.

```
memcpy( pFormatCtxOutFl->streams[ nb_audStrOut ], pFormatCtxOutFl->streams[ i ], 
        sizeof( AVStream ) );
```

Пытаюсь записать

```
avformat__write _header( pFormatCtxOutFl, NULL);
```

И тут возникает ошибка

```
0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x00000024".
```

Что за параметр option? Который передается вторым в avformat_ write_ header()?
Мне кажется ошибка именно в нем!
И помогите пожалуйста с моими дальнейшими действиями, как мне записать аудио данные из другого файла?

Мои предположения:
1) Читать фрейм
2) Если там аудио то декодировать
3) Потом как то записать его в другой файл

А если так то как записать его в другой файл?

Заранее спасибо!